# Using Magento's method="removeItem" to remove js ONLY for IE8 and below

Tags: magento-1.7, xml

Does anyone know why the following doesn't work for removing items from IE8 and below, but does work for adding items?

```
<action method="removeItem">
    <type>skin_js</type>
    <name>notforIE8.js</name>
    <params/>
    <if>lt IE 9</if>
</action>
```

It removes the js file in all browsers.

Answer (score 10):

It doesn't work because the `<if>` is not parsed by `removeItem`. Actually it's not parsed by the `addItem` method either. It is added for all browsers, but there is an `if` statement around it and some browsers ignore the file.
Instead of trying to remove it for IE less than v9, I suggest adding it for ie9 or more.

```
<action method="addItem">
    <type>skin_js</type>
    <name>notforIE8.js</name>
    <params/>
    <if>gte IE 9</if>
</action>
```

Answer (score 7):

Those `<if/>` parameters don't work the way you think they do.

The `addItem`, `addJs`, `addCSS`, etc. methods are for adding tags to the head of the HTML document.  The additional `<if>gte IE 9</if>` parameter is used to tell Magento "Hey, render these tags with *conditional comments*.  If you take a look at the rendered HTML for one of those `add` calls, it will look something like this.

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
...
<![endif]-->
```

That is, surrounded by an Internet Explorer conditional comment `<!--[if lt IE 7]><![endif]-->`.

With that in mind. The `removeItem` method is used to **remove** a tag for rendering that had been previously added.  When you use this method, you're telling Magento

> Hey, that thing I wanted you to render before?  Don't render it now, I changed my mind.

Since you're completely removing the item from rendering, the idea of conditional comments in an `<if/>` tag loses all meaning.

Put another way, the `<if/>` paramater doesn't stop anything from being rendered.  Instead, it controls **how** things are rendered.  The `removeItem` method simply removes an item from being rendered.

Comment: Aha, didn't realise they were basically just conditionals, makes sense now as to why they're not working!